# Como pasar datos de mi DB a un select option?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, mariadb

Inteno obtener datos ya registrados en mi base de datos y mostrarlos en un select option pero por el momento me aparece vacio el elemento. Que me estará faltando para que este completo

```
const Adoptions = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/adoption/adoptions")
      .then((adoptionsResponse) => adoptionsResponse.json())
      .then((adoptions) => setAdoptions(adoptions.data));
  }, []);

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const handleChangeUser = (event) => {
    setUsers(event.target.value);
  };

  const [pets, setPets] = useState([]);
  const handleChangePet = (event) => {
    setPets(event.target.value);
  };

  const [date, setDate] = useState("");
  const handleChangeDate = (event) => {
    setDate(event.target.value);
  };
  const [adoptions, setAdoptions] = useState([]);
  const handleChangeAdoption = (event) => {
    setAdoptions(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Adoption Form</h1>

      <select >{users.map((user) => (<option key={user.id}>{user.name}</option>))}</select>

      <select value="pet">{pets.map((pet) => (<option key={pet.id}>{pet.alias}</option>))}
      </select>
    </div>
  )

}
export default Adoptions
```

Así lo tengo hasta el momento, la otra parte de mi API si funciona correctamente nada mas falta agregar el apartado de adopciones. Cabe mencionar que soy un poco nuevo en todo esto!

Comment: Tu `setAdoptions` si esta definido ? por que no se ve en el código que muestras. de igual manera `adoptions` si tiene información ?

Comment: Ya lo actualize a como está completo.

Comment: Te da algún tipo de error ? solo no veo que hagas uso de `setAdoptions`, igual puse una respuesta de como debería ser tu select

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu **Endpoint** no tiene problemas y regresa los datos como se espera, unicamente sería llenar tu `select` con la información obtenida algo como lo siguiente

```
<select>{adoptions.map((a) => (<option key={a.id}>{a.value}</option>))}</select>
```

no veo cual sea el problema para que no funcione.